# Finding the inverse of a symbolic matrix with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to find the inverse of the following matrix

```
g  = Matrix([[r**2,0],[0,r**2*sin(theta)**2]])
```

where the respective terms are of type:

```
<class 'sympy.core.power.Pow'>
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Zero'>
<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Zero'>
<class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'>
```

When I try to execute the command

```
g.inv()
```

I get the following error message :

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'is_Rational'
```

I am receiving the matrix g as a function parameter. The weird part is that if I hardcode the matrix, I receive no error, and the correct inverse is calculated.

Comment: Get the latest development version of SymPy. This bug has been corrected.

Comment: This version here : http://www.sympy.org/en/download.html ? I checked mine, which is 0.7.5.

Comment: That did the trick. I installed the 0.7.7 dev version of sympy. Now, the inverse of the matrix is found, without leading to the above error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered by Francesco Bonazzi :

> Get the latest development version of SymPy. This bug has been corrected.